# block hostnames and IPs with php

Tags: php, geolocation, geotargetting

I want to block some hostnames and ips from accessing my website, I use this codde to =block only one hostname or ip:

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ipz = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ($hostname === "blocked hostname" || $ipz == "blokced ip" ){
echo "redirect to some url";
}
else {
echo "show site content";
}
?>
```

But I have a long list hof hostnames and IPs to be blocked, I want to add all those bad IPs and hostnames I have in a separated file, and then check if the visitors hostname or IP is on that list or not.
how can I do that and keep to site loading fast ?

Thanks

Comment: If you have blocked ip's and host's in array, just do if stetment with in_array() function...

Comment: could you please show me how?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the best way to go? My ISP uses DHCP so sometimes I get an ip address of the chap down the road! Is that fair?

Comment: technicly I want to block proxy IPs and known bad hostnames , not to block regular ones

Comment: @JawadMira - but people can change their IP address or hostname at a flip of the switch - so the exercise is pointless. Get them to log in using https. Then you will know who(?) they are

Comment: usualy dynamic IPs are not proxies, some visitors try to hide their real countris using proxy servers, those that I want to block

Comment: All my traffic goes thru a proxy. And it is dynamic. Just questioning the futility of embarking on this adventure. Perhaps supplying a username and password would be simpler?

Comment: yes, I do have members area, but alos they could join from proxy! and hide their real country

Comment: @JawadMira - Does that matter that they hide their location? 'cos you have to maintain this database as to what are the dodgy hostnames/ips and what ones are no longer dodgy. Seems a lot of effort.

Comment: yeah, but I'm getting lot of chinese ppl joining my site but using US proxies to see US content, witch is too bad for me

Comment: @JawadMira - Why is that bad? idiot - Chinese government are a bunch of a*********

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First way, put all your ip in a single file, separated by a newline. Then, you'll do :

```
$ips = file("ips.txt", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if (in_array($hostname, $ips) || (in_array($ipz, $ips)) {
  // redirect to some content for banned guyz
  die();
}
// real things
```

If you need more info about file() flags, you can read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

For security reasons, you may put your "ips.txt" file in a folder unavailable from the outside.

Second way, you have a sql table where all ips are stored :

```
require_once("config.php");
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$base}", $user, $password);
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ipz = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select count(*) from banned_ips where ip IN (?, ?)");
$sth->execute(array($hostname, $ipz));
$count = $sth->fetchColumn();
if ($count > 0) {
    // do some stuffs with banned user
    die();
}
// do some stuffs with normal users
```

Comment: in case the ips.txt file becomes very large, would that slow down the site?

Comment: I'm getting this error 'Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object in /home/monk/public_html/prox.php on line 9' where that line is '$count = $sth->execute(array($hostname, $ipz))->fetchColumn();'

Comment: this indicate a mysql error: did you created the "banned_ips" table with a field "ip" where every ip are? did you changed user/password/host and db name? did you tried to display errors (`print_r($dbh->errorInfo());`) ?

Comment: remove the `->fetchColumn()` and use a `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` to show and tell me what's wrong

Comment: I did those changes and now I'm getting this error    Fatal error: Call to a member function print_r() on a non-object in /home/monk/public_html/prox.php on line 9

Comment: `$count = $sth->execute(array($hostname, $ipz)); print_r($dbh->errorInfo());`

Comment: Okey, then, just after `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$base}", $user, $password);`, put `    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` you'll get an exception.

Comment: did that and still having this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object in , and the line is '    $count = $sth->execute(array($hostname, $ipz))->fetchColumn();'

Comment: Please try [this code](http://pastebin.com/egJ9EA3P) I can't explain myself easily on a comment field :-)

Comment: thanks you a lot, you was very helpfull, I did some searching and solved the problem before you comment, I also edited your answer with the final working code, again thank you

Answer (score -1):

I actually just implemented this feature last week into one of my sites. I have a MySQL Table with an IP column, and a reason column so both the user can see why their IP is banned, and whoever is able to edit/view the list.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM banned_ips';
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$bannedips = array($row['ip']);
};
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (in_array($ip, $bannedips))
{
header('Location: some url');
};
```

Comment: so is it faster to handle it in php and mysql? or adding the bad ips/hostnames in separated file and including it in the script would be better?

Comment: why are you promoting `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: @Nile I think it's easier to put it into MySQL so that you could always create an interface for people to use, instead of having a file that one person has access to

Comment: @bhooks why not doing `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM banned_ips WHERE ip = '(some ip)'` and check if you have > 0 rows? your method is far from a nice solution

Comment: so witch way is faster? using file.txt to list bad ips/hots or using database ? just tru=ying to sue less resources and making the site load faster

Comment: @bhooks don't use `mysql_*` functions

Comment: @Nile , what can we replace mysql_*  by?